# C# how to reference the class from assembly

Tags: c#, class, generics, .net-assembly

I wanna dynamic generate a Class,and use the class as T in List.But I can't make the dymanic Class as T in List,I need your help and give me some advice,or the article relation.Here is my way to finalize:

I have generated a dynamic assemly.It contains a public Class named BookOrder.
Here is  apart of my Code:

```
 string path="D:\BookOrderAssembly.dll";
 Assembly assem = Assembly.LoadFile(path);
 Type tp=assem.GetType("BookOrder");-- get the class type in this assembly
```

I wanna  know how  can I use this BookOrder as a Class in a List,I can't find the way in MSDN.

I want to get :

```
List<BookOrder>  lstorder=new List<BookOrder>();
```

I wanna use  the Class Type in assembly  to come true that    `List<BookOrder> LSD = DbUtils.DeserializeJsonToList<BookOrder>(ss);` The ss is a JSON with array just like  `{"DDH":"2015040401","FDBH":"6","Kcmxlist":[{"SPCODE":"00015860","SL":"2"}]}`.
I wanna use the BookOrder as T in List ,please give me some advice.Thank u

Comment: What do you want to do with it? Since you don't have the type at compile time, you can't even access members of it. So just use a `List<object>`. Alternatively, instantiate the `List<BookOrder>` through reflection.

Comment: I don't have the answer, but you need to be aware that a backslash in C# string literals is an escape character. You need to use either `string path = @"D:\BookOrderAssembly.dll";` or `string path = "D:\\BookOrderAssembly.dll";`.

Comment: You can use `Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(List<>).MakeGenericType(new Type[]{tp}))` and place it in a `dynamic`.

Comment: How have you tried to refer to the DLL in your project?

Comment: thank u for all your help.I wanna use  the Class Type in assembly  to come true that   `List<ClassFromAssembly> LSD = DbUtils.DeserializeJsonToList<ClassFromAssembly>(ss);` The ss is a JSON with array just like  `{"DDH":"2015040401","FDBH":"6","Kcmxlist":[{"SPCODE":"00015860","SL":"2"}]}`.The ClassFromAssembly must be the Class Type in an Assembly.So I don't need a instance,but need to get the Class Type from the Assembly.Can anyone help me?